# ./src/App.jsx Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Por favor ayuda con el siguiente error en React

{
"name": "login-react-1",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"firebase": "^8.7.1",
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-router": "^5.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import "Routes" instead of "Route":

```
import {
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

"react-router-dom"' has no exported member named 'Routes'. Did you mean 'Route'?